# how to have two headings on the same line in html

Tags: html, css, html-heading

I want to have two headings h2 and h3 on the same horizontal rule one on the left and the other on the right. They have a HR underneath them and I want them to be at the same distance from this HR.

I tried making them both inline and have one float right and the other left. The problem with doing so was with h3 as it is smaller than h2 vertically it was centered at half the h2's length.

h2 was kinda like sitting on the hr and h3 kinda looked like floating in mid air.

I kinda wanted them to be like both sitting on the hr.

```
h2{
display:inline;
float:left;
}
h3{
display:inline;
float:right;
}
```

I was talking about visually describing the situation.

Comment: The best way you can describe is with code.

Comment: Show us some code, what have you tried?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You'd need to wrap the two headings in a `div` tag, and have that div tag use a style that does `clear: both`. e.g:

```
<div style="clear: both">
    <h2 style="float: left">Heading 1</h2>
    <h3 style="float: right">Heading 2</h3>
</div>
<hr />
```

Having the `hr` **after** the `div` tag will ensure that it is pushed beneath both headers.

Or something very similar to that. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 13):

You should only need to do one of:

- Make them both `inline` (or `inline-block`)
- Set them to `float` left or right

You should be able to adjust the `height`, `padding`, or `margin` properties of the smaller heading to compensate for its positioning.  I recommend setting both headings to have the same `height`.

See this [live jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HwWkz/) for an example.

(code of the jsFiddle):

**CSS**

```
h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

h2, h3 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<h2>Big Heading</h2>
<h3>Small(er) Heading</h3>
<hr />​
```

Comment: I tried the margin,padding everything but the float I guess keeps on overriding them

Answer (score 6):

Display property 'inline-block' will place both headers next to each other. You can run this code snippet to see it

```html
<h1 style="display: inline-block" >Text 1</h1>
<h1 style="display: inline-block" >Text 2</h1>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation about the code.

Answer (score 4):

The Css vertical-align property should help you out here:

```
vertical-align: bottom;
```

is what you need for your smaller header :)

[Vertical-Align](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)

Comment: tried it doesnt work .. vertical align works without the float:right

Answer (score 4):

Check my sample solution

```
<h5 style="float: left; width: 50%;">Employee: Employee Name</h5>
<h5 style="float: right; width: 50%; text-align: right;">Employee: Employee Name</h5>
```

This will divide your page into two and insert the two header elements to the right and left part equally.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will allow you to have two headings on the same line, the first left-aligned and the second right-aligned, and has the added advantage of keeping both headings on the same baseline.

The HTML Part:

```
<h1 class="text-left-right">
    <span class="left-text">Heading Goes Here</span>
    <span class="byline">Byline here</span>
</h1>
```

And the CSS:

```
.text-left-right {
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
}
.left-text {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.byline {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgba(140, 140, 140, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a `span` with the `style="float: right"` element inside the `h1` element. So you can add a "goto top of the page" link, with a unicode arrow link button.

```html
<h1 id="myAnchor">Headline Text
<span style="float: right"><a href="#top" aria-hidden="true">↥</a></span>
</h1>
```